# What is the difference between ascx and .cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this in my index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/Test.cshtml");
}
```

and this in my controller:

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

I am not able to understand what is the fundamental difference between using .ascx and .cshtml in RenderPartial method? Both works for me. What is the real difference? Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different view engines you can use for asp.net mvc3 web applications. Razor (.cshtml) and ASPX (*.aspx / *.ascx).

Take a look at this post about their differences:

[What is the difference between Razor and ASPX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702231/what-is-the-difference-between-razor-and-aspx)